# How does -on_load work in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I seem to not fully understand, how the -on_load directive works. In a module i have written i have a function to initialize an ets table and populate it with some data. This function works properly when calling it explicitly. However: i thought it would be nice, if the ets table would be populated "automatically" when the module is loaded. But this does not seem to work, because `ets:info(filesig)` tells me "undefined" after loading the module. The relevant code looks something like:

```
...

-on_load(init/0),

init() ->
    % load filesig database into ETS
    {_, Signatures} = file:consult("path to a file"),

    ets:new(filesig, [set, protected, named_table]),
    ets:insert(filesig, Signatures),

    ok.

...
```

I've tested it from within the erlang shell. Any hints for me, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html#id84067) says that this code runs in a newly spawned process which terminates as soon as the function returns.

The ETS table you create gets deleted once the owning process terminates. This is a standard ETS behavior. Here's what the [ets man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) mentions about it:

> Note that there is no automatic garbage collection for tables. Even if
>   there are no references to a table from any process, it will not
>   automatically be destroyed unless the owner process terminates. It can
>   be destroyed explicitly by using delete/1. The default owner is the
>   process that created the table. Table ownership can be transferred at
>   process termination by using the heir option or explicitly by calling
>   give_away/3.